# How do I get alerted when SQL Server 2008 replication fails for any reason?

Tags: sql-server, replication

We have managed to get SQL Server 2008 merge replication working.  However, it will occasionally fail for inexplicable reasons (currently, it's because of MSSQL_REPL-2147201021.)  When this happens, our data does not get replicated for days!  Our admins needs alerted when that is the case.

So, the question is: how can we be alerted when SQL Server 2008 replication fails for *any* reason.  I also am worried about signal vs. noise.  I just want to know when my data is not being synchronized and the error number that is causing the problem.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[All About Automatically Monitoring Replication Agent Failures](https://repltalk.com/2010/05/09/all-about-automatically-monitoring-replication-agent-failures/) for a description of using [scom](/questions/tagged/scom) for this.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the alerts under SQL Agent to see if the Replication alerts are enabled?
You may also be able to query the destination data and see if it is getting newly dated info - if the query doesn't get expected dates, send a page.